Why isn't the following sympy code recognizing s?
I am writing code to calculate the transfer function of an RC circuit. It is supposed to result in an equation with a numerator and denominator where the denominator contains an s term. The latex output shows that it does but the code doesn't recognize it. here is the code:
import lcapy
import sympy as sp
from IPython.display import display, Math

# Define the symbolic variable s
s = sp.symbols('s')

# Define a simple RC circuit netlist
netlist = """
R1 1 2
C1 2 0
"""

# Create a Circuit object from the netlist
circuit = lcapy.Circuit(netlist)

# Find the transfer function from node (0) to node (2)
h = circuit.transfer(0, 1, 0, 2).simplify()
display(Math(f"H(s) = {h.latex()}"))

# Check if h has 's'
if not h.has(s):
    raise ValueError("Transfer function h does not contain 's'.")

I tried running the above code in colab. I am expecting for it to not throw the ValueError "Transfer function h does not contain 's.'." but it keeps on throwing this error. The error serves as a test to see if the program is able to recognize that there is an s in the denominator but it doesn't recognize it even though it obviously is there.

I'm not familiar with lcapy, but it seems likely that lcapy.s is a different symbol from the s you created.

Right.  Your sympy variable s is completely disconnected from your lcapy circuit.  You can access the s domain by using circuit.s_model.

As mentioned in the above comments, your s is different from the one used by lcapy. We can inspect the differences like this:
print(s.assumptions0)
# {'commutative': True}

print(lcapy.s.assumptions0)
# {'complex': True, 'commutative': True, 'infinite': False, 'finite': True}

s != lcapy.s
# True

As you can see, two symbols can share the same name. But if they have different assumptions, then they are different symbols.
